# How to get date of next Sunday while using dynamic variables for date in PHP?

Tags: php

I've used PHP code to get next Sunday's date. But I want to get next Sunday's date based on the dynamic date like-

```
$y = '2018';
$m = '09';
$d = '16';
$dts = $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d;
$nextDate = date($dts,strtotime('next Sunday'));
echo $nextDate;
```

I am unable to get next Sunday date.

I would appreciate any help from you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks so much, @NigelRen. it works

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use DateTime

```
$nextDate = (new DateTime())->modify('next Sunday')->format('Y-m-d');
```

And likewise you can put any valid date in the constructor call.

```
$nextDate = (new DateTime($dts))->modify('next Sunday')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Then it will modify it from that starting date.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP's `strtotime` with a value of "next Sunday" is correct. The problem is that the format values you're passing to `date` are the literal values of "2018","09", and "16", rather than the format string (it looks like you want "Y-m-d").

This will get you the date for next Sunday from the current date:

```
$nextDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next Sunday'));
```

If you want to get the next Sunday from any given date, you simply need to pass the date as a second argument to `strtotime`:

```
$y = '2018';
$m = '09';
$d = '16';
$dts = $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d;
$nextDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next Sunday', strtotime($dts)));
echo $nextDate;
```